# C read reallocates buffer

Tags: c, io

I'm reading standard input on linux. I provide read with buffer that has insufficient length (only two characters), buffer should overflow and Segmentation fault should occure. However the program runs ok. Why?

Compiled with:

```
gcc file.c -ansi
```

Runned with:

```
echo abcd | ./a.out
```

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define STDIN 0

int main() {

    /* This buffer is intentionally too small for input */
    char * smallBuffer = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * 2 );

    int readedBytes;
    readedBytes = read(STDIN, smallBuffer, sizeof(char) * 4);

    printf("Readed: %i, String:'%s'\n", readedBytes, smallBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Readed: 4, String:'abcd'
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in a C program.  And `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: You happened to hit memory which still belongs to your process. You will probably get horrible runtime errors with other variables being overwritten in real code. This is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally wrong to expect a segmentation fault in this kind of cases. You see, buffer overflows result in [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It means that a behavior of such code is unpredictable. It may or may not result in segmentation fault.

Technically, when you allocate a buffer of two bytes, for example, there are two possible scenarios.

First is when a buffer is allocated on stack. The stack itself is larger than 2 bytes, and if you overflow that buffer, memory protection unit will still allow you to write at the memory "outside" that buffer. In this case you won't get a segmentation, but could potentially mess up other variables stored "nearby" on the stack, this kind of situation is generally referred to as “stack smashing”.

The second possible scenario is allocating memory dynamically (i.e. using `malloc()`). In that case it is very likely that actually allocated buffer is a larger or is placed on the same page as memory allocated/reserved before. In that case, the program would write past the buffer of two bytes. It may or may not receive a segmentation violation signal but nevertheless the behavior is undefined.

Sometimes, such cases are hard to find without extremely special care. There are tools that help to trace alike issues. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is one of them, for example.

On a side note, you may only expect a segmentation fault if you know for sure that a virtual address you are using is invalid or is being protected from read, write, or execution by the [memory protection unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection) (which might not exist at all on the hardware you are running your application).

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` guarantees to provide you with *at least* the amount of memory you request. To see an error you can use a program such as valgrind and you'll see the following:

```
 ==22265== Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
 ==22265==    at 0x4F188B0: __read_nocancel (syscall-template.S:82)
 ==22265==    by 0x4005B4: main (in /home/def/p/cm/Git/git/a.out)
 ==22265==  Address 0x51f1042 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
 ==22265==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
 ==22265==    by 0x400595: main (in /home/def/p/cm/Git/git/a.out)
```

Comment: malloc grants nothing, especially under linux, see the "optimistic memory allocation strategy" or "overcommit" topic.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the program overwrites some of its own memory. OS does not notice this.

Segmentation fault occurs when a process tries to access a memory that does not belong to it. However, an operating system assigns memory blocks not on a per-byte basis, but with larger blocks - pages (e.g. size of 4 KB is frequently used). So when you allocate two bytes, these two bytes are placed by heap manager on some memory page (either previously allocated or a new one), and the whole memory page is marked as belonging to your process. It is highly probable that these two bytes will not end up at the end of memory page, that is your program will be able to write after these two bytes without any OS exception at the time of writing (but most probably it will fire at you later).

Answer (score 0):

Too small a buffer is not a guarantee that the program will crash. It depends on what data exists in the bytes following the buffer, how the compiler arranges the executable, and how the operating system organizes memory.
Chances are that the bytes following your buffer already "belong" to your program and are padding or otherwise store nothing of import.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd parameter is not the size of the buffer, but the number of bytes to read. So you call the function and say "here's a stream, read 4 bytes from it and put in in this buffer". But it doesn't know the buffer size (it only knows the file size). So what it happens it reads as much as it can do and puts it in your buffer (assuming you supplied a buffer large enough). So what you get then is memory corruption. You're program may work OK in this simple case, but usually it just fails unexpectedly in some other place.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should put particular attention to what `malloc()` really does, a `malloc()` call under linux it's not only unlikely to fail but it's not granting you a real reservation of space even if it's returning a positive response.

This behaviour is tipically named "optimistic memory allocation strategy" or "overcommit", it's strictly related to the kernel and programming in C under linux it's not that easy, in my opinion you should switch to C++, you will find a familiar syntax to start with and it makes much more sense to use C++ for productivity than C this days, also with a simple RAII approach C++ is safer than C.